# How do you inherit all of the fields of UserAdmin to view in

Tags: django, django-admin

How do I inherit all of the existing Fieldsets from UserAdmin and then add the additional field from my CustomUser?  I can add my custom fields but can't seem to get all the existing UserAdmin Fieldset to regenerate the default admin view. The suggestion of "UserAdmin.fieldsets + ...." from another post doesn't seem to work.

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'date_of_birth', 'SSN', 'Primary_address', 'Primary_address_zipcode', 'is_admin','last_login','date_joined')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
            (None, {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `get_fieldsets` method of ModelAdmin:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        all_fields = fs[0][1]['fields']
        all_fields += ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
        return all_fields
```

Comment: I get this error:  Exception Value: too many values to unpack